# are timestamps reliable to make synced timers with?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

I'm trying to make simple, synced timer using timestamp.
like this - if node server starts a timer and sends expiration time to the client. then browser at client side checks it until it passes expiration time.
so if a timer in node expires, the timer matches to server one should also expire at the same time.

my question is, can timestamp guarantee that two timers expired at the same time?

Comment: it depends. What if the client changes their clock e.g. to the year 2030 - then it will think it has expired if Date.now() > expireTimestamp

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell thanks for the reply! is that common situation?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I thought most client environment such as chrome on windows or android is pretty synced so I wonder whether timestamps between other devices is same when each device is well synced with ntp server.

Comment: @ThomasMiller no just no. I suggest you learn about the difficulty of keeping time.